# Редактировать опции в Open Cart

Tags: opencart

Всем добрый вечер) Помогите пожалуйста найти файл, в котором можно изменить сортировку опции выбора размера, или может ее как-то иначе можно изменить? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы они были по порядку

Answer (score 0):

Массив опции из БД, для вывода на сайте получаются запросом

```
$product_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option po LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` o ON (po.option_id = o.option_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_description od ON (o.option_id = od.option_id) WHERE po.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND od.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.sort_order");
```

в файле /catalog/model/catalog/product.php, `public function getProductOptions($product_id)`
и сортируются согласно "Порядку сортировки" который задается опциям в админке, в разделе Каталог>>Опции
[image: Скриншот из админ панели]
Или можно запрос из БД изменить на свое усмотрение.